# What is the proper way to resolve Eclipse warning "isn't parameterized"?

Tags: java, eclipse, warnings

I'm trying to clean up some warnings in some old Java code (in Eclipse), and I'm unsure what the proper thing to do is in this case.  The block looks more or less like this:

```
Transferable content = getToolkit().getSystemClipboard().getContents( null );
java.util.List clipboardFileList = null;

if( content.isDataFlavorSupported( DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor ) ) {
  try {
    clipboardFileList = (java.util.List)content.getTransferData(
      DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor);
  }
  /* Do other crap, etc. */
}
```

The List generates a warning as it isn't parameterized, however, if I parameterize it with `<File>`, which I'm pretty sure is what it requires, it complains that it can't convert from `Object` to `List<File>`.  I could merely suppress the unchecked warning for the function, but would prefer to avoid that if there is a "good" solution. Thoughts?

Comment: So getTransferData() returns an Object?

Comment: Whoops, left out the line that says what content is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would recommend explicitly casting the result to `List<File>` and suppressing the warning. According to [the documentation](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/datatransfer/DataFlavor.html#javaFileListFlavor):

> `public static final DataFlavor javaFileListFlavor`
>
> To transfer a list of files to/from Java (and the underlying platform) a DataFlavor of this type/subtype and representation class of `java.util.List` is used. Each element of the list is required/guaranteed to be of type `java.io.File`.

In such a situation where the documentation clearly defines the data type, feel free to ignore the warnings, as per Item 24 of Joshua Bloch's [Effective Java](http://books.google.ca/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&pg=PA117&lpg=PA117&dq=joshua+bloch+suppresswarnings&source=bl&ots=yXIoLku1VZ&sig=rteiYuQey--2_gQ6DCwN2E9iSuA&hl=en&ei=wwKpS865O8Kblge51vGxDw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CAgQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=&f=false) (page 116):

> If you can't eliminate a warning, and you can prove that the code that provoked the warning is typesafe, then (and only then) suppress the warning with an `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` annotation.

Comment: That makes sense to me and sort of the direction I was leaning toward. Just curious if there was a "better" solution.

Comment: @Morinar: Understandable. The purpose of the answer was to offer an expert's (Joshua Bloch's) rationale behind your decision. :)

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
java.util.List<?>
```

Comment: That seems to do the trick. That merely telling it that I don't know what the type is? Or is it more complicated than that?

Comment: @Morinar, it does a little more: it says the list is of a specific type, which is unknown - whereas the raw type means it's a list that can contain elements of different types (and therefore is not type safe).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to use `<?>`. This just works fine for me?

```
Object obj = null;
List<File> aa = (List<File>)obj;
```

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. It's not that it can't do it, it's that it is an `Unchecked Cast from Object to List<File>`.

Comment: Oh. Sorry I use IDEA and it didn't give any warnings.